# how set toggle function for different id

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I want different buttons with id and a unique function for toggle, but i can set the variable.

```
var clicked = false;

var abcElements = document.querySelectorAll('.cellInput');

// Set their ids
for (var i = 0; i < abcElements.length; i++){

    abcElements[i].id = 'target-' + i;

    $("#target-"+i).click(function () {

    if (!clicked) {
        // do something

    } else {
        // do something
    }

    clicked = !clicked;

})

}
```

Comment: so whats your question/problem?

Comment: You probably don't even need to bind each ID, whatever it is you are trying to do in the functions, it can most likely be done with data attributes and binding to the class instead

Comment: Given your snippet, there's literally no reason to give them an id.  You already have each element to bind the click element on.  You do not have to give them an id, to look them up by.  *You already have them*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of the click for each element, you cannot use a shared global variable.  You can, however, toggle a class to keep track of state on each element.

```js
$('.cellInput').on('click', function(e){
  var $this = $(e.target);
  
  if (!$this.hasClass('clicked')) {
    $this.addClass('clicked');
    // do something
  } else {
    $this.removeClass('clicked');
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: And why is that a problem?